# MySQL Query, bulk insertion

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I have a bulk data for insertion in MYSQL Tables, let use suppose, 10k in one time,
What I am doing is store the data in an XML file and then go for insertion (data is around 50K rows), It will take a lot of time, Is there any option for bulk insertion in MySQL tables.

Thanks in advance,
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) can help. It is the fastest way to load data from text file.

Comment: Is it possible If I Have a XML File, Can I use make bulk insert in MYSQL on basis of XML file data, If yes, ?Can you Explain .. Thanks

Comment: XML cannot be inserted directly. But there are many (free) off the shelf utilities that will convert the xml data to flat data. That can be your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to disable de indexes before insertion and enable them afterwards to recreate them.

ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE
ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS

Comment: Is there any way to Bulk insertion of Data from Collection to Mysql Database.

Comment: What do you mean with Collection?